# Webpack unexpected token react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, webpack, ledgerjs

I'm trying to integrate a connection to Ledger nano X devices, into a native Swift package. Unfortunately Ledger only provide an SDK as a [ReactNative module](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledgerjs). I dislike ReactNative and really don't want to integrate it into my entire Swift package, and force it onto my users, just for this one library.

I've had limited success in the past converting NodeModules into plain .js files that I can run directly with iOS's `JavascriptContext`. I've used webpack to bundle it up into a single plain js file (no `require`, `import`, `export` etc keywords). Adding a native Swift wrapper around that lets me keep all the messy dev setup and tools out of my project and just leverage the plain JS when needed for small use-cases. I've very little experience with this and what i've done in the past isn't working, hours of googling hasn't gotten me any closer.

Building the entire `Ledgerjs` with webpack was throwing up errors, since I only need pieces of it I started trying to get one of the sub-packages `@ledgerhq/react-native-hw-transport-ble` to build. I forked the project and added this `webpack.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "ledger_transport_ble": ['./src/awaitsBleOn.ts', './src/BleTransport.ts', './src/monitorCharacteristic.ts', './src/remapErrors.ts', './src/timer.ts', './src/types.ts']
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx'],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
        fallback: { 
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") 
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        library: ['[name]'],
        libraryTarget: "var"
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'] })
    ],
};
```

with this `.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-flow"
    ]
}
```

and I get back this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-ble-plx/index.js 11:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| export { State, LogLevel, ConnectionPriority, ScanCallbackType, ScanMode } from './src/TypeDefinition'
| 
> export type {
|   Subscription,
|   DeviceId,
 @ ./src/BleTransport.ts 87:29-60
```

Instructions online where to add the .babelrc file that I added above, but it made no difference. Have I missed a step somewhere? Or is there something else I should be doing?